# Why can't I properly place the Depth Camera in the Beginner Model Editor tutorial?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have been trying to go through the Beginner Model Editor tutorial.  I am not able to place the "Depth Camera" on the top of the vehicle.  I don't seem to be able to move it in "z."  Sometimes it disappears altogether as I try to move it around.

I am using Gazebo 7.4.0 and Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14682/why-can%27t-i-properly-place-the-depth-camera-in-the-beginner-model-editor-tutorial?/) by [beartrap](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2883/beartrap/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-10-24**:
How are you moving it? Make sure you're dragging the blue arrow. The more perpendicular your view  angle is to the arrow, the more detailed movements you'll be able to make. You can also try making use the the align or snap tools.

**Comment by [beartrap](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2883/beartrap/) on 2016-10-24**:
I was not dragging the blue arrow, rather I was trying to move it as if it were a Power Point object.  It is working for me now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I needed to drag the arrows -- blue arrow for z movement.  I was trying to drag the body of the object instead.

---

Originally posted by [beartrap](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2883/beartrap/) with karma: 16 on 2016-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0